# How to convert current date to timestamp in Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datetime, time

I want to convert current date to timestamp.Suppose todays date is 26/4/2019 , then i am doing like this.

```
const current = new Date();
const timestamp = current.getTime();
```

but this gives me 1556532767266. 
When i am getting date from this , it shows me 'Mon Apr 26 2019 10:12:47' in UTC and 'Mon Apr 26 2019 15:42:47' in local.
but i want in this '**Mon Apr 26 2019 00:00:00**', which is night 12Am

Can anyone please help me how to get like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set Hours/Min/Seconds to 0 and getTime()

```
const current = new Date();

current.setHours(0)

current.setMinutes(0)

current.setSeconds(0)

current.setMilliseconds(0)

const timestamp = current.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, and many others when dealing with date/times, use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

```
var moment = require("moment");
var current_timestamp = moment().format("ddd MMM D YYYY 00:00:00");
```

A moment() call initializes to the current time, but Moment objects can also accept JavaScript Date objects:

```
var current_timestamp = moment(new Date());
```

Check out all the formats available for Moment to convert timestamps any way you want.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/